# employees who work in multiple department using first name and last name

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate a SQL query to find out employees who work in multiple department using first name and last name

Comment: Are you looking for a stored procedure? Where are the first name/last name coming from? What have you tried so far?

Comment: first name and last name are the name of the columns in employee table

Comment: Well, its too hard to guess.Please post some code that you have tried here.

Comment: A little bit more effort should be put in "do my homework" questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for this query. This will give you the employees working in multiple department.

```
select 
    FirstName, LastName, Count(Department) 
from 
    Employee
where 
    FirstName = '<FirstName>' -- Add  condition here
    and LastName = '<LastName>'
group by 
    FirstName, LastName
having 
    Count(Department) > 1
```